# Problem replacing numbers with words from a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have two files:

In the first one (champions.csv) I have the number and the name of some LoL champions

```sh
1,Annie
2,Olaf
3,Galio
4,Twisted Fate
5,Xin Zhao
6,Urgot
7,LeBlanc
8,Vladimir
9,Fiddlesticks
10,Kayle
11,Master Yi
```

In the second one (top.csv) I have couples of champions (first and second column) and the number of won matches by them (third column)

```
2,1,3
3,1,5
4,1,6
5,1,1
6,1,10
7,1,9
8,1,11
10,4,12
7,5,2
3,3,6
```

I need to substitute the numbers of the second file with the respective names of the first file.

I tried using awk and storing the names in an array but it didn't work

```
lengthChampions=`cat champions.csv | wc -l`

for i in `seq 1 $length`; do
    name=`cat champions.csv | head -$i | tail -1 | awk -F',' '{print $2}'`

    champions[$i]=$name
done

for i in `seq 1 10`; do
    champion1=${champions[`cat top.csv | head -$i | tail -1 | awk -F',' '{print $1}'`]}
    champion2=${champions[`cat top.csv | head -$i | tail -1 | awk -F',' '{print $2}'`]}

    awk -F',' 'NR=='$i' {$1='$champion1'} {$2='$champion2'} {print $1","$2","$3}' top.csv > tmptop.csv && mv tmptop.csv top.csv
done
```

I would like a solution for this problem maybe with less code than this. The result should be something like that (not the actual result for my files):

```
Ahri,Ashe,1502
Camille,Ezreal,892
Ekko,Dr. Mundo,777
Fizz,Caitlyn,650
Gnar,Ezreal,578
Fiora,Irelia,452
Janna,Graves,321
Jax,Jinx,245
Ashe,Corki,151
Katarina,Lee Sin,102
```

Comment: Not at all clear, from where `Ashe` is coming from your output? Please edit your samples which look relevant to expected output and let us know then.

Comment: Where did the numbers like `1502` in your output come from? Why does the number `1` in the 2nd column of your input file become different strings in the 2nd column of each line of your output file?

Comment: Sorry about the wrong numbers and names in the result. The champion.csv is more much bigger and the numbers of the second file are bigger too. The result is just an example of what can be.

Comment: @GuillermoMartínez, you need not to post full file, just provide samples of input and expected output by which we could understand the logic of getting output.

Comment: @GuillermoMartínez the [mcve] you provide to demonstrate your requirements needs to show the output that you want to be produced from the input you show. Showing output that would come from some other set of input isn't nearly as useful! See [ask] if that's not clear. Oh, and if I were you I'd include what you want output if a number from top.csv doesn't exist in champions.csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be accomplished in a single awk call. associate numbers with champions in an array and use it for replacing numbers in second file.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$1=a[$1];$2=a[$2]} 1' champions.csv top.csv 
Olaf,Annie,3
Galio,Annie,5
Twisted Fate,Annie,6
Xin Zhao,Annie,1
Urgot,Annie,10
LeBlanc,Annie,9
Vladimir,Annie,11
Kayle,Twisted Fate,12
LeBlanc,Xin Zhao,2
Galio,Galio,6
```

in case there should be some numbers in `top.csv` that don't exist in `champions.csv`, use the following instead to prevent those numbers from being deleted:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){$1=a[$1]} ($2 in a){$2=a[$2]} 1' champions.csv top.csv
```

Comment: Simple and robust. In fact it can't be any simpler I guess.

Comment: I'm trying this command but I get this:`
```shellscript
,3nnie
,5nnie
,6nnied Fate
,1nnieao
,10nie
,9nniec
,11nieir
,12isted Fate
,2in Zhao
,6alio
```

Comment: @GuillermoMartínez that happens when your files have windows line endings. fix it using this command `dos2unix champions.csv top.csv`

Comment: or insert `{sub(/\r/,"")}` before `NR==FNR...`

Comment: @GuillermoMartínez: or add `-v RS='\r*\n'` to your awk command in this special case.

Comment: @Cyrus yes, but multichar `RS` is gawk-specific

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the *2nd* column of *champions.csv* isn't too huge, (*i.e.* larger than the maximum size of the `bash` array `${c[@]}`), then using `bash` and `cut`:

```
readarray -t -O 1 c < <(cut -d, -f2 champions.csv)
while IFS=, read x y z; do 
    printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "${c[$x]}" "${c[$y]}" "$z" 
done < top.csv
```

Output:

```
Olaf,Annie,3
Galio,Annie,5
Twisted Fate,Annie,6
Xin Zhao,Annie,1
Urgot,Annie,10
LeBlanc,Annie,9
Vladimir,Annie,11
Kayle,Twisted Fate,12
LeBlanc,Xin Zhao,2
Galio,Galio,6
```